# How to get the sub-sub-components of a JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame` which looks like this:

```
JFrame
|-Top Level JPanel
|--JPanel
|---All of the JPanel Components
|--JPanel
|---All of the JPanel Components
|--JPanel
|---All of the JPanel Components
```

As you can see there is a container panel holding three sub-JPanels and some components underneath these sub-JPanels and these are the components i need access to.

The reason i cant do this is because i need access to it in a button of one of the sub-JPanel.

Here is my current code:

```
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                CreateNewProjectMenuFrame createNewProjectMenuFrame = (CreateNewProjectMenuFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) event.getSource());
                
                ArrayList<Component> createNewProjectMenuFrameComponents = new ArrayList<Component>(Arrays.asList(createNewProjectMenuFrame.getComponents()));
                ArrayList<Component> createNewProjectMenuFrameChildComponents;
                for (Component component : createNewProjectMenuFrameComponents) {
                    createNewProjectMenuFrameChildComponents.addAll(new ArrayList<Component>(Arrays.asList(component.getComponents())))
                }
                
                ProjectData projectData = new ProjectData();
                
                if (createNewProjectMenuFrame != null) {
                    createNewProjectMenuFrame.dispose();  // dispose of it
                }
            }
        });
```

However, the `Component` object does not have a `getComponents()` function so how do i get access to these components?

Comment: Generally, you would include update methods in the JPanel classes.  You would access an update method with chained methods; getFrame().getUpperPanel().updateJLabelText(text);  getFrame is a method in the JFrame class, getUpperPanel is a method in the JFrame class, and updateJLabelText is a method in the first (upper) JPanel class.

Comment: I suggest you keep references as class fields to the components when you creat them. If you want a more details suggestion, I will need to see more code. Create a [mcve] that illustrates the minimum of what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a recursive call.

[image: Disable All In Container]

**E.G.**

```
    public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable) {
        Component[] components = container.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.setEnabled(enable);
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                enableComponents((Container)component, enable);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class RecursiveCallInContainer {

    public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable) {
        Component[] components = container.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.setEnabled(enable);
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                enableComponents((Container) component, enable);
            }
        }
    }

    RecursiveCallInContainer() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gui.add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
        container.add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
            tb.add(new JButton("Button"));
        }

        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        container.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.WEST);

        container.add(new JTextArea(5, 20), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JCheckBox enable = new JCheckBox("Enable", true);
        enable.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
            enableComponents(container, enable.isSelected());
        });
        gui.add(enable, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new RecursiveCallInContainer();
        });
    }
}
```